# Change text size when selected

Tags: android

Is there a way to increase the text size for a `TextView` when selected?

Comment: Didn't you try adding an `OnClickListener`?

Comment: I know this could be done with a listener. I was wondering if there is an .xml file like a size selector I could use.

Comment: as i have told u in another post... A Wrapper Class is the best solution if a selector xml is not available...

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this help you.

package com.android.sample;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SampleActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private TextView mTextView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        mTextView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mTextView.setTextSize(50);
            }
        });
    }
}
```